# Calculate start date with calendar of workdays

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please, help with my problem.

I have 2 tables:

- calendar with workdays and holidays;
- table with calculate.

I need to calc **startDate ** = [calcDt + 5 workdays (excluding weekends and holidays)].
See example.

My calendar:

```
CREATE TABLE #Calendar(
     id DATE
    ,isWorkDay BIT
    ,isHoliday BIT  
);

INSERT INTO #Calendar(
     id
    ,isWorkDay
    ,isHoliday  
)
VALUES
     ('2022-01-14',1,0)
    ,('2022-01-15',0,0)
    ,('2022-01-16',0,0)
    ,('2022-01-17',1,0)
    ,('2022-01-18',1,0)
    ,('2022-01-19',1,0)
    ,('2022-01-20',1,0)
    ,('2022-01-21',1,0)
    ,('2022-01-22',0,0)
    ,('2022-01-23',0,0)
    ,('2022-01-24',1,0)
    ,('2022-01-25',1,0)
    ,('2022-01-26',1,0)
    ,('2022-01-27',1,0)
    ,('2022-01-28',1,0);
```

My table with calculate:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data(
     calcDate DATE
    ,startDate DATE
);

INSERT INTO #Data(
    calcDate
)
VALUES
     ('2022-01-14')
    ,('2022-01-14')
    ,('2022-01-14')
    ,('2022-01-15')
    ,('2022-01-16')
    ,('2022-01-17')
    ,('2022-01-18');
```

I need to calculate startDate = calcDate + 5 workdays, example:

```
calcDate      startDate
2022-01-14    2022-01-20  
2022-01-14    2022-01-20
2022-01-14    2022-01-20
2022-01-15    2022-01-21
2022-01-16    2022-01-21
2022-01-17    2022-01-21
2022-01-18    2022-01-24
```

Comment: Which Database are you using

Comment: What did you try so far and why didn't it work? There are quite [lots of example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+add+date) related to this topic

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: In my case I use mssql

Comment: [DATEADD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is the function you can use to add a number of days to an existing date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `UPDATE` with a `CROSS APPLY` to the calendar will work.

```
UPDATE t
SET startDate = a.startDate
FROM #Data t
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT MAX(id) AS startDate
  FROM (
    SELECT TOP 5 cal.id 
    FROM #Calendar cal 
    WHERE cal.id BETWEEN t.calcDate
                     AND DATEADD(month, 1, t.calcDate)
      AND cal.isWorkDay = 1
      AND cal.isHoliday = 0
    ORDER BY cal.id
  ) q
) a;
```

| calcDate | startDate |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-14 | 2022-01-20 |
| 2022-01-15 | 2022-01-21 |
| 2022-01-16 | 2022-01-21 |
| 2022-01-17 | 2022-01-21 |
| 2022-01-18 | 2022-01-24 |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e80fdd26980feb01306c459e9346a388)*

Comment: Nice. Btw, I should note that the Sql is including t.calcDate in the count of 5. So it would get the expected result. So startDate is actually t.calcDate + 4 workdays